# NodeJs - Javascript - readFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js

We are making a module in Nodejs and we want to read a JSON file in User Folder (Windows) but the system var "%userprofile%" don't working with fs.readfilesync function.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var myConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('%userprofile%/manager-cli.json', 'utf8'));
```

Error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\angular\manager-cli\%userprofile%\manager-cli.json'
```

Does anyone know a solution to the problem? Or an alternative.

Source: https://github.com/jserra91/manager-cli/blob/master/bin/global.js

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `process.env.USERPROFILE`.

So in your example:

`var myConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.env.USERPROFILE + '/manager-cli.json', 'utf8'));`

Comment: Note: In `process.env` you can see all windows environment variables. It is case sensitive, so use correct uppercase/lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package like [`ospath`](https://github.com/jprichardson/ospath):

```
const path     = require('path');
const ospath   = require('ospath');
const fs       = require('fs');

const filePath = path.join(ospath.home(), 'manager-cli.json');
const myConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'));
// or possibly:
// const myConfig = require(filePath);
```